# Unable to use existing Java packages in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm learning Java from Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java. After reading about packages early through the book, I thought I had got it, but when I decided to use the supplementary code(in the form of a single ZIP), I'm not so sure anymore.

The ZIP file contains packages in the correct hierarchy. I've an extracted copy of the ZIP too. Let's call this folder **TIJ4**. Both the ZIP and the folder are located on my Desktop. I'm working with an example `Shapes.java` which has an import statement like this: 
`import polymorphism.shape.*;`. I imported this folder in the Project Properties>Libraries>Add external class folder. The strange thing is that Eclipse does not show an error on the `import` line, yet it cannot resolve names to types. I could manually create a package, then a class from within Eclipse, but isn't there an easier way to do this?

I've gooogled about this but nobody seems to have the exact problem as me. Here's what I've got so far:

1)New Java Project created. Created a class file `Shapes.java` in the project:
[image: New Java Project created. Created a class file <code>Shapes.java</code> in the project:]

2) Project Properties>Libraries>Add External Class Folder. Selected my folder **TIJ4**. Notice that the error on the `import` is now gone. Apparently Eclipse has found the `polymorphism` package.
[image: Selected my folder **TIJ4**. Notice that the error on the <code>import</code> is now gone. Apparently Eclipse has found the <code>polymorphism</code> package.]

3)But I still get `XXX cannot be resolved to a type` errors all over the place!

what do I do? I also tried Project>Build Path>Add external archives and selected the ZIP, however, ended up in the same place.

Comment: Add that TlJ4 folder contents to src folder and check it(copy and paste). remove TlJ4 folder from references libraries

Comment: @vini Didn't help. Copying TIJ4 folder to src causes a package `Snippet` and a file called Snippet.java to e created automatically.

Comment: @black_stallion sorry not the folder but the folders inside TlJ4 folder should be copied to src folder.

Comment: @Gutenberg That didn't help either.

Comment: @vini You mean through Eclipse only, right? Tried copying `polymorphism` as well as `polymorphism.shape` manually. Still no go!

Comment: Does the zip file contain only Java source files? I guess there are no compiled class files inside the zip. Is that right?

Comment: @MadhusuthananSeetharam Yes you are right. The ZIP(and thus the folder) contains only .java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Zip file contains only Java sources, you will have to compile them. Simple way, right now, is extract them into the src directory in your eclipse project. That way they will be compiled and automatically included in the classpath.

The reason for not able to resolve the classes even the import error goes away, is the zip file contains the directories that satisfy the package structure but there are no compiled classes (the .class files) are found in them.

Comment: Yes that seems to work. But this does not use the package feature of Java, does it really? Because I no longer have to `import` anything in any file. It just runs fine. (In fact, Eclipse shows an error at the failed package-which does not exist)

Comment: Before answering your question, let me know if the file RandomShapeGenerator.java is present in the dir structure polymorphism/shapes under src?

Comment: So does that mean, for an `import` to work successfully, you need the .class files for those classes?

Comment: Yes, infact all the .java files containing the required classes are in the src folder of my project. And therefore, I presume (as Eclipse confirms) I'm using the default package?

Comment: Yes. Packaging is organizing compiled class files into packages (read directories) for the class loaders to locate and load. These directories can be either on disk or compressed in a jar or zip archive. If you look under the bin directory of your eclipse project you will see the class files neatly organized as per their packages. Use the 'Navigator' view instead of the 'package explorer' to look at the directory structure.

Comment: So, in short I didn't have the .java files compiled. Suppose I already have .class files,then it would be a simple matter of placing them in the bin folder in the correct package hierarchy, am I right?

Comment: Yes, almost. But bin is a dangerous folder to place your class files as eclipse will clean it up every time it builds the project. You need to place it in a separate folder or package it in a zip or jar file and refer that in the build path or classpath.

Comment: Was my first tryst with Java! Thanks for your time! All's well now. Am now able to use packages properly.